# Async Python Background Task

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a sync method that has a connection updater that checks if a connection is still open, that runs in a background thread. This works as expected and continously

How would the same thing be possible in asyncio ? Would asyncio.ensure_future would be the way to do this or is there another pythonic way to accomplish the same?

```
def main():
    _check_conn = threading.Thread(target=_check_conn_bg)
    _check_conn.daemon = True
    _check_conn.start()

def _check_conn_bg():
    while True:
        #do checking code
```

Comment: What's wrong with `asyncio.ensure_future`?

Comment: Nothing wrong, just wondering if that would be the way to go with this

Comment: Just try it and find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `asyncio.ensure_future()`. In your coroutine make sure your code won't block the loop (otherwise use `loop.run_in_executor()`) It's also good to catch `asyncio.CancelledError` exceptions.

```py
import asyncio


class Connection:
    pass


async def _check_conn_bg(conn: Connection):
    try:
        while True:
            # do checking code
            print(f'Checking connection: {conn}')

            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print('Conn check task cancelled')


def main():
    asyncio.ensure_future(_check_conn_bg(Connection()))

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.